# Анимация при скролле. Показ элемента

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, прокрутка

В body есть несколько контейнер, идущие друг за другом, каждый имеет высоту 100vh. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при скролле один элемент какбы съезжал вверх, а следующий постепенно открывался. Эффект, как будто оба абсолютно позиционированы, но у первого индекс 2, а у второго - 1. И когда скролишь первый уезжает вверх и открывает второй элемент, который стоит на месте, как при top=0. Я пробовал манипуляции с этими свойствами, но выходит криво, так как скролится весь документ и двигается все... Не получилось, чтобы скрол действовал только на один элемент, а документ замораживался.

Comment: как минимум добавьте пример кода

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поиграть со свойством fixed для предыдущего блока, z-index для обоих элементов и добавь полупрозрачный блок vh и vw 100% bg-color rgba(255,255,255,0.6)
Как пример, сам не пробовал такое